# Why does the "ave" function in R have this name, since it is not limited to computing averages?

Tags: r, statistics, average, lapply

I recently discovered the "ave" function in R but cannot understand why it is actually called "ave". Under the default settings, the function returns the mean, perhaps split by groups if specified, though we can apply any other function to this function (e.g. sum, diff...etc.). It therefore seems misleading to name the function "ave" since the function is not limited to averages, and moreover it seems like just a wrapper for lapply if one looks at the ave function itself. I guess I have missed something blindingly obvious...?! Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this function predates R. Note that `FUN = mean` has always been the default.

Comment: Thanks - I just don't understand why its still called ave if we can do lots of other thing aside computing averages! Was just bugging me, and I wondered if I had missed something...

Comment: The R developers are very conservative with changes. There is really no need to rename this function. But there would be substantial cost (i.e., a lot of code in packages and user scripts would have to be checked and need to be updated to reflect that change).

Comment: I see. Yes that makes sense. Thank you @Roland